# Bitbucket pipeline - error installing pre-commit ts-lint

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

I have a step in my pipeline that runs our configured pre-commit on Bitbucket:

```
...
- step:
    name: Passing linters
    image: python:3.7-slim-stretch
    script:
      - pip3 install "pre-commit==2.17.0"
      - apt-get update && apt-get --assume-yes install git
      - pre-commit run --all-files
```

No changes were made but it suddenly stopped working.

The pipeline result:

```
+ pre-commit run --all-files
[INFO] Initializing environment for https://github.com/psf/black.
[INFO] Initializing environment for https://github.com/psf/black:click==8.0.4.
[INFO] Initializing environment for https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks.
[INFO] Initializing environment for https://github.com/maximevast/pre-commit-tslint/.
[INFO] Initializing environment for https://github.com/maximevast/pre-commit-tslint/:tslint-react@4.1.0,tslint@5.20.1,typescript@4.0.2.
[INFO] Installing environment for https://github.com/psf/black.
[INFO] Once installed this environment will be reused.
[INFO] This may take a few minutes...
[INFO] Installing environment for https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks.
[INFO] Once installed this environment will be reused.
[INFO] This may take a few minutes...
[INFO] Installing environment for https://github.com/maximevast/pre-commit-tslint/.
[INFO] Once installed this environment will be reused.
[INFO] This may take a few minutes...
An unexpected error has occurred: CalledProcessError: command: ('/root/.cache/pre-commit/repo1234/node_env-default/bin/node', '/root/.cache/pre-commit/repo1234/node_env-default/bin/npm', 'install', '--dev', '--prod', '--ignore-prepublish', '--no-progress', '--no-save')
return code: 1
expected return code: 0
stdout: (none)
stderr:
    /root/.cache/pre-commit/repo1234/node_env-default/bin/node: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by /root/.cache/pre-commit/repo1234/node_env-default/bin/node)
    /root/.cache/pre-commit/repo1234/node_env-default/bin/node: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.25' not found (required by /root/.cache/pre-commit/repo1234/node_env-default/bin/node)
    /root/.cache/pre-commit/repo1234/node_env-default/bin/node: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by /root/.cache/pre-commit/repo1234/node_env-default/bin/node)
    
Check the log at /root/.cache/pre-commit/pre-commit.log
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`pre-commit` utilizes `nodeenv` to bootstrap node environments

it does this by downloading a copy of `node` and provisioning an environment (when `node` is not available).  a few days ago node 18.x was released and the prebuilt binaries require a relatively-recent version of glibc

there's a few ways you can work around this:

### 1. select a specific version of `node` using [`language_version`](https://pre-commit.com/#config-language_version) / [`default_language_version`](https://pre-commit.com/#top_level-default_language_version)

```yaml
# using default_language_version
default_language_version:
    node: 16.14.2

# on the hook itself
repos:
-   repo: https://github.com/maximevast/pre-commit-tslint
    rev: ...
    hooks:
    -   id: tslint
        language_version: 16.14.2
```

### 2. use a newer base image

`stretch` is a bit old, perhaps try instead `3.7-slim-buster` instead ?

this will get you a more modern version of glibc

```yaml
    image: python:3.7-slim-buster
```

### 3. install `node` into your image

this will skip the "download node" step of pre-commit by default (specifically it'll default to `language_version: system` when a suitable `node` is detected)

this will vary based on your image setup

---

disclaimer: I created pre-commit